# Angular service not storing data between two controllers

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I am trying to use a service to set `title` in controller1 and then access `title` in controller2.

`sharedProperties.setTitle(title)` works in controller1, but when I try to get the title in controller2, it gets "title" (the initial value) instead of the new value.

I've also tried storing `title` in an object but it didn't work.

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var title = "title"

    return {
        getTitle: function () {
            return title;
        },
        setTitle: function (val) {
            title = val;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('controller1', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function ($scope, sharedProperties) {

    $('body').on("click", "button[name=btnListItem]", function () {
        // gets the title
        var title = $(this).text();
        // sets the title for storage in a service
        sharedProperties.setTitle(title);
    });

}]);

app.controller('controller2', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function ($scope, sharedProperties) {

    $scope.sharedTitle = function() { 
            return sharedProperties.getTitle(); 
    }; 

}]);
```

And in my view, I have `{{ sharedTitle() }}` which should, as I understand it, update the title text with the new title.

Also, in case this is relevant: the two controllers are linked to two different html pages.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Updated button listener:

```
$('body').on("click", "button[name=btnListItem]", function () {
    // gets the text of the button (title)
    var title = $(this).text();

    sharedTitle(title);
    alert(sharedProperties.getTitle());
    document.location.href = '/nextscreen.html';
});

$scope.sharedTitle = function (title) {
    sharedProperties.setTitle(title);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be correct in your sample code. I setup jsfiddle and it seems work correctly. Finding out a difference between my jsfiddle and your actual code would help you to find the problem you should solve.

Javascript:

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
.service('sharedProperties', function(){
    var title = 'title';
    return {
        getTitle: function(){
            return title;
        },
        setTitle: function(val){
            title = val;
        }
    };
})
.controller('controller1', function($scope, sharedProperties){
    $scope.change_title = function(newvalue){
        sharedProperties.setTitle(newvalue);
    };
})
.controller('controller2', function($scope, sharedProperties){
    $scope.sharedTitle = function(){
        return sharedProperties.getTitle();
    };
})
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        <input ng-model="newvalue">
        <button ng-click="change_title(newvalue)">Change Title</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="controller2">
        <span>{{sharedTitle()}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[My jsfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/11/)

Comment: hmm... My title is coming from a button: `list.append('<button ng-click="sharedTitle(title)" name="btnListItem" class="list-group-item">' + title + '</button>');`. I added ng-click and call the shared_title function in my controller. It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can my transfer to a different page (see edit: `document.location.href = '/nextscreen.html';`) affect what is stored in the service? This next page links with controller2.

Comment: I got it. Your way to move to next page, `document.location.href`, definitely init the state of everything in angularjs including `sharedProperties` service. You should use $routeProvider and $location service instead of document object.

Comment: Thanks, using $routeProvider and $location works! :)

Comment: I'm grad to hear it !

Answer (score 0):

You have to print `console.log(sharedProperties.getTitle());` Dont need return from controller.

So your code of controller2 is `$scope.sharedTitle = sharedProperties.getTitle();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`$apply`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) so that angular can process changes made outside of the angular context (in this case changes made by jQuery).

```
$('body').on("click", "button[name=btnListItem]", function () {
    // gets the title
    var title = $(this).text();
    // sets the title for storage in a service
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      sharedProperties.setTitle(title);
    });

});
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UpvVVHFnB8Lb4NB9bCIG?p=preview)

That said, this is **BAD PRACTICE** because you're going against what angular is meant for. Check [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). There are cases when you need to use `$apply` like when integrating third party plugins but this is not one of those cases.